# jquery: why is content going on the next line?

Tags: jquery

I'm using a  [jquery quiz plugin](https://github.com/QuickenLoans/SlickQuiz) that was written off of jQuery v1.9.1 and includes that version in the distribution.  When I try to use the current jQuery Mobile which includes the later jQuery v1.11.1, the quiz has the following problem:

[image: quiz questions not lined up]

Namely, the answers no longer line up next to the radial buttons,as they do when I use the plugin's included older jquery, which I don't want to as it causes other problems in the page.

The code that does this markup as best as I can tell is in slickQuiz.js

```js
                    // prepare a name for the answer inputs based on the question
                    var selectAny     = question.select_any ? question.select_any : false,
                        forceCheckbox = question.force_checkbox ? question.force_checkbox : false,
                        checkbox      = (truths > 1 && !selectAny) || forceCheckbox,
                        inputName     = $element.attr('id') + '_question' + (count - 1),
                        inputType     = checkbox ? 'checkbox' : 'radio';

                    if( count == quizValues.questions.length ) {
                        nextQuestionClass = nextQuestionClass + ' ' + lastQuestionClass;
                    }


                     for (i in answers) {
                            if (answers.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                                answer   = answers[i],
                                optionId = inputName + '_' + i.toString();

                                // If question has >1 true answers and is not a select any, use checkboxes; otherwise, radios
                                var input = '<input id="' + optionId + '" name="' + inputName +
                                            '" type="' + inputType + '" /> ';

                                var optionLabel = '<label for="' + optionId + '">' + answer.option + '</label>';

                                var answerContent = $('<li></li>')
                                    .append(input)
                                    .append(optionLabel);
                                answerHTML.append(answerContent);
                            }
                        }
```

Can you please tell me what needs to change, so the each answer option, i.e. "1", "2", and "3", once again stays adjacent to the radial button?

I'm running this locally in eclipse.  Here's what I see when I put it in FireFox:

```
view-source:file:///C:/Users/Reto/eclipse-workspace/Site/WebContent/Test.html


  <div class="collapse" data-role="collapsible" data-mini="true" data-     collapsed-icon="carat-r" data-expanded-icon="carat-d"
  data-collapsed="false" data-content-theme="false">
     <a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline" data-transition="pop">Basic Popup</a>
  <div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
    <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.</p>
  </div>
  <h4>Getting Started</h4>
  <p>I'm the collapsible content without a theme.</p>

  <h1 class="quizName">Quiz/Prep to continue on</h1>
  <div id="slickQuiz">

    <div class="quizArea">
      <div class="quizHeader">
        <!-- where the quiz main copy goes -->

        <a class="button startQuiz" href="#">Get Started!</a>
      </div>

      <!-- where the quiz gets built -->
    </div>

    <div class="quizResults">
      <h3 class="quizScore">
        You Scored: <span> <!-- where the quiz score goes -->
        </span>
      </h3>

      <h3 class="quizLevel">
        <strong>Ranking:</strong> <span> <!-- where the quiz ranking level goes -->
        </span>
      </h3>

      <div class="quizResultsCopy">
        <!-- where the quiz result copy goes -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please note I added more reference code.  Thanks.

Comment: show the resulting markup

Comment: Can you please add the CSS as well?

Comment: Adding, the html markup doesn't show in the page for some reason, how is that possible?  Is it in the DOM?  Can you download quiz and try with later jquery version?  I added as best as I can at present, please see bottom of question.

Comment: Please note the quiz comes with a page, index.html, ready to run an example quiz.   Also unfortunately I need to run out the door to an appt, so if I don't answer immediately back, that's why.

Comment: I'm back trying to make it work ... any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the css included from jQuery Mobile that altered the quiz display.  So in the distribution slickQuiz.js file, I forced the style to be inline as follows:

```
var optionLabel = '<label style="display:inline" for="' + optionId + '">' + answer.option + '</label>';
```