# jQuery: why would someone want to append to a closed list element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As no response on [my other jquery question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46699854/jquery-why-is-content-going-on-the-next-line), I want to zero in on a few lines of code so that you might help me understand.   So firstly, this quiz runs multiple questions on a button push, and in my limited understanding, this is direct DOM manipulation and does not show up when one does "view source" in the browser. Does that sound right?

Secondly, I'm perplexed by the lines:

```js
 var input = '<input id="' + optionId + '" name="' + inputName +
                                            '" type="' + inputType + '" /> ';

                                var optionLabel = '<label for="' + optionId + '">' + answer.option + '</label>';
                            
                                var answerContent = $('<li></li>')
                                    .append(input)
                                    .append(optionLabel);
                                answerHTML.append(answerContent);
```

Does it make sense to append code like this to an empty

```
 <li></li>
```

element?  Am I misreading that this is an append after the element?  It does appear to work under the older jquery version listed in the other question, just not the new version (I'm guessing this is the source of the error as shown in the image of the other question, but am not sure).

I just tried:

```
var answerContent = '<li>' + input + optionLabel + '</li>';
```

and it produced the same result, still a bug as shown in picture.

Comment: I just changed the answerContent line and tried this instead:var answerContent = '<li>' + input + optionLabel + '</li>';    It produced the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this is direct DOM manipulation and does not show up when one does "view source" in the browser

Yes. Do not use "view source", look at the DOM in the browser's developer tools (F12).

> Am I misreading that this is an append after the element?

Yes. http://api.jquery.com/append/

That being said, do not build HTML by concatenating strings. This will break as soon as the strings you use contain characters that have meaning in HTML, like `<`, `>` or `&`. This can happen at least in `answer.option` here.

jQuery allows passing the element properties as an object with keys and values,  this is safe to use and involves much less typing of `' + '`. For simple cases like this one it's enough.

```
$('<li></li>')
    .append( $('<input>', {id: optionId, name: inputName, type: inputType}) )
    .append( $('<label>', {htmlFor: optionId, text: answer.option}) )
    .appendTo("#answerHTML");
```

The philosophy here is "create something and then do something to it". Note how because of that, this code doesn't even need any helper variables. Not even `answerHTML` needs to be a variable, as long as the target element can be picket easily with a selector.

For more complex cases of DOM building using jQuery to create every tiny bit becomes tedious. Use an HTML templating library like [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

Comment: Interesting answer, @Tomalak. How this behaves in terms of speed? I normally use arrays/strings to create html elements because I thought that it should be faster than jQuery objects manipulation.

Comment: Thanks @Tomalak, but this is plugin library I would like to use.  Can you please try from the other question listed, what the issue is.  ... Please download code quick, try index.html with the later jquery listed?

Comment: This would be much faster than you need it to be.  Don't make assumptions about speed, [measure it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time). Also keep in mind that the fastest code in the world is worthless when it has bugs.